# PHP unidentified index when getting SQL data

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Good Day, I am tasked to have an original and discounted price in our website, using PHP. Previously the original price is already present, now I am trying to add a second price by adding variables in the customer management system. The problem is that I get

> Notice: Undefined index:

even when I add a discounted price value alongside the original price. I added a new column for the new discounted price option in my phpmyadmin database but I still get that index error.

Any help would be appreciated and ill explain the situation with codes and screenshots.

[price error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDhKf.png)
[phpmyadmin columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzzzI.png)

codes with original price and discounted price (the "d_price" is the one with unidentified index)

1.

```
  <div class="col-md-12"><hr></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">ORIGINAL PRICE</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="Original Price"
                        value="<?php
                          if(isset($_POST['price'])) {
                            echo($_POST['price']);
                          } else {
                            echo($rowProduct['price']);
                          } ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12"><hr></div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">DISCOUNTED PRICE</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="d_price" placeholder="Discounted Price"
                        value="<?php
                          if(isset($_POST['d_price'])) {
                            echo($_POST['d_price']);
                          } else {
                            echo($rowProduct['d_price']);
                          } ?>">
                    </div>
```

2.

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-align-center">
                  <h4>ORIGINAL PRICE</h4>
                    <strike><h4><?php  echo($rowProduct['price']); ?> PHP</h4></strike>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 text-align-center">
                  <h4>DISCOUNTED PRICE</h4>
                    <h4><?php  echo($rowProduct['d_price']); ?> PHP</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
```

3. (this is the if statement snippet for the save button)

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'SAVE')
  {
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $d_price = $_POST['d_price'];
```

Again 'price' works normally while 'd_price' shows the error. I hope I have provided enough information to not get my question downvoted.

I think this is where $rowProduct originates:

```
  $producttagid = isset($_GET['t']) ? $_GET['t'] : 1;
  $merchantid = isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m'] : NULL;

  $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  $lstProductTag = $mcProductTag->SelectLst($db);
  $lstProductTagLink = $mcProductTagLink->SelectLst_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  $lstMerchant = $mcMerchant->SelectLst($db, 1, 10000);



$productid = $mcProduct->InsertObj($db, $merchantid, $title, $subtitle, $body, $recstatus, $price, $d_price, $qty, $createddate, $createdby, $featured, $packageid, $expirationdays);
```

heres a screenshot of my phpmyadmin database, I already added d_price in the Product row but I still get unidentified index. Im providing as much information as I can.

[image: phpmyadmin]

I think these lines of code interact with the SQL database via PDO

[image: database link]

[image: $db]

EDIT: here are all the locations of SelectObj_ByProductId (searched with notepad++)

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\-api\ProductsBookmarkToggle.api.php (1 hit)
    Line 65:     $api['productData'] = $api['productModel']->SelectObj_ByProductId(
  C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cards\info-detailed.vc.php (2 hits)
    Line 45:   $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
    Line 54:     $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cards\info.vc.php (2 hits)
    Line 46:   $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
    Line 65:       $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\clinic\info-detailed.vc.php (2 hits)
    Line 45:   $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
    Line 54:     $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\cms\products_edit.vc.php (1 hit)
    Line 151:   $rowProduct = $mcProduct->SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid);
  C:\xampp\htdocs\mwc_canuto\_mc\Product.mc.php (1 hit)
    Line 205:   public function SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid) {
```

EDIT: I added d_price in what seems to be the insert object function, I still get unidentified index

```
  /********** Insert Object **********/

   public function InsertObj($db, $merchantid, $title, $subtitle, $body, $recstatus, $price, $d_price, $qty, $createddate, $createdby, $featured, $packageid, $expirationdays) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " INSERT INTO `product`
          (merchantid, title, subtitle, body, recstatus, price, d_price, qty, createddate, createdby, featured, packageid, expirationdays)
        VALUES
          (:merchantid, :title, :subtitle, :body, :recstatus, :price, :d_price, :qty, :createddate, :createdby, :featured, :packageid, :expirationdays) "
    );

    // cast bit type data to int else it wont save properly
    $featured = (int)$featured;

    $stmt->bindValue(':merchantid', $merchantid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':subtitle', $subtitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':body', $body, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':recstatus', $recstatus, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':price', $price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':d_price', $d_price, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':qty', $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':createddate', $createddate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':createdby', $createdby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':featured', $featured, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':packageid', $packageid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':expirationdays', $expirationdays, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $insertId = $db->lastInsertId();

    return $insertId;
  }
```

[image: unidentified index]

[image: line 139]

Comment: I'll take a guess and say that this `<h4><?php  echo($rowProduct['d_price']); ?> PHP</h4>` is line 139? If so, use a conditional statement for it also or a ternary operator.

Comment: yes thats line 139 with the unidentified index. also i tried to explain the situation of the codes here in order to avoid that duplicate question mark.

Comment: may i see a smple of a conditional statement or a ternary operator using my code?

Comment: You already have one going now `if(isset($_POST['d_price'])) {
                            echo($_POST['d_price']);
                          }` - Base yourself on that. The ternary operator example can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: i woud just like to admit and be honest after i read the ternary operator example and how my if else statement still outputs unidentified index: I Don't Get It

Comment: The manuals shows `$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];`.

Comment: i tried:                             <?php
                          if (empty($_POST['d_price'])) {
                              $action = 'default';
                          } else {
                              $action = $_POST['d_price'];
                          }

                          ?>"> but i still get unidentified index

Comment: Check your query then. If it's not happening in your form then it's in the query.

Comment: I could not find a query when browsing through the php files, if it is possible i would like an exmaple how PHP fetches data from SQL

Comment: I can't do anything else for you here. I reopened the question, so you can see if someone else can spot something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: can you post the code for `SelectObj_ByProductId($db, $productid)` function ?

Comment: added all locations of  SelectObj_ByProductId

Comment: i added "d_price" in all lines of code with "price" in them like in the insert object function, i also added the "d_price" column in phpmyadmin, yet i still get unidentified index when trying to display it.

Comment: same error, i added d_price in $stmt, and im not sure what you mean by declare a variable, i already added d_price in insert object and have place it in the database

Comment: Why don't you print your query result object and see if it have the column?

Comment: Use `echo "<pre>"; print_r($rowProduct); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: how do i print the query object?

Comment: I have updated the comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184007/discussion-between-ussaid-iqbal-and-hadrian-clayton).